# LOCC distinguishability of a mixture of Bell states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

Consider the Bell states
\begin{align}
|\psi^0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle),& \quad 
|\psi^1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle - |11\rangle), \\
|\phi^0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle),& \quad 
|\phi^1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle), 
\end{align}
and let $\psi^0,\psi^1,\phi^0,\phi^1$ denote their corresponding density matrices. Now I want to consider the three mixings of the Bell states, namely
$$ \rho_0 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^0 + \psi^1), \quad
\rho_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\phi^0 + \phi^1), $$
and
$$ \sigma_0 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^0 + \phi^0), \quad
\sigma_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^1 + \phi^1), $$
and finally
$$ \xi_0 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^0 + \phi^1), \quad
\xi_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\psi^1 + \phi^0). $$
It is easy to see $\rho_0,\rho_1$ are perfectly distinguishable by [LOCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOCC) (measure in computational basis), and it is easy to see $\sigma_0,\sigma_1$ are perfectly distinguishable by LOCC (measure in Hadamard basis). However, it is not straight forward for me to see that $\xi_0,\xi_1$ are perfectly distinguishable by LOCC, although I would be very much surprised, if this was not the case.

Any help is appreciated, and if it turns out $\xi_0,\xi_1$ are indeed indistinguishable, I would very much appreciate an intuitive reasoning behind this phenomenon!

Comment: As one avenue to explore, have you tried to calculate the Schmidt bases for those states?

Comment: I never got around to figuring this out, but somehow I find myself back at this problem. Can you elaborate on your suggestion? I mean Schmidt Decomposition is something we can do for pure states, right? But $\xi_0$, $\xi_1$ are mixed states.

Comment: As written here they are pure states.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify: $\psi_0 = |\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|$, så $\xi_0$ is a mixture of two distinct pure states.

Comment: Ah. That is atrocious notation, independently of whether you include a note of it in the text or not. I've got nothing much to say about those mixtures, other than: do not use misleading notation.